# size limit for the sql_variant exceeds

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio

I am trying to save image from fileupload control into the database

```
public Byte[] bytes;
Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
SqlDataSource2.Update();

protected void SqlDataSource2_Updating(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
   e.Command.Parameters["@project_file"].Value = bytes;
}
```

My database `project_file` field is set to `varbinary(MAX)`,

but it is throwing an error

> **Parameter '@project_file' exceeds the size limit for the sql_variant datatype.**

Please suggest some solution

Comment: Your way of indenting the code is... creative. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a quote from [MSDN on binary and varbinary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx):

> Variable-length binary data. n can be
>   a value from 1 through 8,000. max
>   indicates that the maximum storage
>   size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size
>   is the actual length of the data
>   entered + 2 bytes. The data that is
>   entered can be 0 bytes in length. The
>   ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is
>   binary varying.

`varbinary(MAX)` can hold an image that is ~2GB of size.

**Solution to your problem:**

You forgot to specify the type in your code. You need to set the correct [SqlDbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx).

`e.Command.Parameters["@project_file"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary`

What you should also do i set the correct [Size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx).

Comment: If the down-voter could please leave a comment if something I said is wrong, it would be much apprechiated.

Comment: This worked for me:    ((SqlParameter)e.Command.Parameters["@FileData"]).SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarBinary;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that sql server assign the type of the parameter as "SQL_Variant".

Try to assing the DbType :

```
e.Command.Parameters["@project_file"].SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Image
e.Command.Parameters["@project_file"].Value = bytes;
```

Comment: it solves my problem thanks.but i did not get the concept behind that.why after setting the type in database we have to set the db type again??

Comment: @saurabh, your code does not know what type of data you send to the database. So what it will do is generalise it to sql_variant and the database expect binary data(varbinary/blob/image).

Comment: @saurabh : the Filip answer is exactly what happened with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use SQL_VARIANT as your datatype in your C# program.  Use the following type instead:

```
Dim binaryStream As SqlBinary
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1904w6t(VS.80).aspx

P.S. when you use datatypes of Image and Blob you kill a kitten. These datatypes are deprecated and store no more then a varbinary(MAX).

Side note on the use of Image vs Varbinary(max):

image
Variable-length binary data from 0 through 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.

varbinary [ ( n | max) ] (maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes.)
Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length. The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx

Comment: Look at the part on ntext,text and image that says important

Comment: ok thanks. Didn't know that. Removed the recommendation for Image/Blob in my answer.